# How do you set a Foreign Key in Visio 2010

Tags: key, visio

I'm working on a EERD in Visio 2010 for an assignment, but I am having issues trying to figure out how to set something as a Foreign Key.

I can figure out how to set the primary keys (which is simple) i just do not have a lot of experience with visio so i can't figure out how to do the FKs.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the entity there is a properties box where you can check or uncheck Primary Keys.

I think Foreign Keys set automatically if you connect entities.